# What is the MediaStore MIME Type for Directory?

Tags: android, file, mediastore, storage-access-framework

**SAF**(Storage Access Framework) have the constant DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR
Which is this string: **vnd.android.document/directory** as MIME Type for the directory.
MediaStore have anything like this for directory?

Below query print corresponding mime type for files and null for directories in Logcat.

```
val uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external_primary")
val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE)
val cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null)

if (cursor != null) {
       while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Log.e("MIME TYPE", "mime type = " + cursor.getString(0))
       }
}
```

Is there any alternate way **using MediaStore API** to determine whether the item is a file or directory ?

Comment: `Query returns null.` ??? I see no query.

Comment: sir I edited my question. can you check

Comment: `volumeName` ??? Incomplete code.

Comment: now changed to Primary Volume

Comment: Not visible in your code. Still incomplete code.

Comment: Now whats the problem? this code running without any issue

Comment: If you get a null its probably a directory. What do you need more? In principle the media store is for indexing files. Not folders.

Comment: null is ok for me,  but when I update DISPLAY_NAME the MIME Type automatically convert into "application/octet-stream". Other files without any extension is also this same MIME Type. So I want to distinguish between file and folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MediaStore have anything like this for directory?

No, sorry.

> Is there any alternate way using MediaStore API to determine whether the item is a file or directory ?

`MediaStore` only contains what you refer to as files.